# Deﬁne f : Z/3Z → Z/3Z by f ([a]) = [2a + 1].

Tags: functions, proof-writing

For this problem, I have to prove the function is well-defined, is surjective, and is injective.

For seeing it is well defined, I have this: Assume [a1] = [a2] in the set of equivalence classes Z/3Z. Then by definition, a1 ≡ a2 (mod 3). So 3 divides a1-a2.

But, would it be legal for me to say by the property of divisibility, then 3|2(a1-a2)+1? It doesn't sound correct, but I need to show that 2(a1)+1≡2(a2)+1(mod 3), so then [2(a1)+1] = [2(a2)+1] so that f([a1]) = f([a2]).

I know that it is onto, because I did the modulo math manually, and saw that every y value was mapped by an x value, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

The same follows for showing it is one-to-one.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $3$ is supposed to divide $f([a_1])-f([a_2])$, not $f([a_1-a_2])$, which is what you wrote down first. As for onto, just checking each of the three possible $y$-values is proof enough, although it's not a method that is recommended once the range of possible values gets large.

Answer (score 0):

Is much easier using the properties of the classes:
$$f ([a]) = [2a + 1]=[2][a]+[1],$$
and $f$ is well defined.

The inverse is $g([a])=[2]([a]+[2])$:
$$g(f([a]))=[2]([2][a]+[1])+[2])=[2]([2][a]+[3])=[4][a]=[a],$$
$$f(g([a]))=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

$3\mid a-b\Rightarrow3\mid2\left(a-b\right)=\left(2a+1\right)-\left(2b+1\right)$
so the function is well-defined.

Denoting $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as $\left\{ \bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2}\right\} $
function $f$ can be recognized as the function prescribed by $\bar{0}\mapsto\bar{1}$,
$\bar{1}\mapsto\bar{0}$ and $\bar{2}\mapsto\bar{2}$.

It is evident that it is bijective with $f^{-1}=f$.